# Add Check constraints in SQL Server: ADD CONSTRAINT vs ADD CHECK

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, constraints, check-constraints, check-constraint

I want use a check constraint for a column in any table in SQL Server 2008.

I would like give a qualified name to the check constraint.

I have seen several syntax version on how to create it:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Roles2016.UsersCRM] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CHECK (([Estado]=(4) OR [Estado]=(3) OR [Estado]=(2) OR [Estado]=(1)))

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Roles2016.UsersCRM] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_UsuariosCRM_Estado] 
        CHECK (([Estado]=(4) OR [Estado]=(3) OR [Estado]=(2) OR [Estado]=(1)))
```

What's difference `ADD CHECK` and `ADD CONSTRAINT` for a check constraint?

Comment: The second syntax allows you to name your constraint. the first doesn't. It's good practice to name constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, but a **very bad habit** to add constraints without a name:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(SomeColumn VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT('test'))
```

will create a `CONSTRAINT` with a random name. Better use this

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(SomeColumn VARCHAR(10) CONSTRAINT DF_YourTable_SomeColumm DEFAULT('test'))
```

This will do the same, but will name the constraint like you want it.

This is **extremely important** if you run upgrade scripts in deployed environments. Just imagine, you want to change a constraint later and the name of this constraint is all different on your customers machines... That's a real pain!

So: Always name your constraints!